# In a loop, dest address cannot apart from current address more than -128~+127 bytes, why?

Tags: loops, assembly, x86, intel

I'm reading the book *Assembly Language for Intel-Based Computers Fifth Edition*.
The author said like the TITLE but he didn't explain.
Is it relative about instruction length?

Comment: yes, this instruction uses only 1 byte to store offset

Comment: @Lashane Then why so? If we use more bytes to store offset, we'll avoid a lot of 'jump destination too far' errors, isn't it better?

Comment: But then code size increases, and that's bad. If most of your loops are tiny, why waste the extra byte?

Comment: @nneonneo It makes sense. But how if I have to write code which violate the rule in a loop? (I'm new to Assembly.)

Comment: Use a longer jump instruction. x86 has a bunch of jump instructions that take different arguments.

Comment: You should know that `loop` is deprecated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756290/loop-loope-loopne http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4880461/is-there-a-list-of-deprecated-x86-instructions

(You may already know that and may just be asking for the sake of complete knowledge, but I thought I'd post it just in case.)

Comment: @Tyler - `loop` is NOT deprecated.  It just was not optimized like small set of most frequently used instructions such as `mov` and `add`.  Feel free to use `loop` whenever it looks comfortable, excluding tight loops when speed is really matters.

Comment: `loop` is one of a number of stupid instructions included in the x86 instruction set to appease the *goto is evil* crowd and introduce structured programming to assembly (see also `enter/leave`, `bounds` etc.). It's a spectacular failure and a waste of encoding space.

Comment: @EOF - wow, there is a _goto is evil crowd_ among _assembly_ programmers?

Comment: @BeeOnRope Well, tbh the comment was a bit hyperbolic even when I wrote it, and I've come to change my views on some of this. `loop` is not intrinsically stupid, and it's only slow because Intel doesn't care. On AMD, it's apparently decent, which makes sense because its really just a fused "compute/conditional branch", potentially being a bit easier to decode than doing the macro-op fusion in the decoders. `enter` is *weird*, `leave` is useful, and there is a genuine need to have efficient bounds checking, so even though `bounds` is a failure it's an understandable one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

think about this in next way, to create loop you need:

```
mov cx, iterations
label:
; loop body
dec cx ; this instruction takes 1 byte
jnz label ; this instruction takes 2 for short and 4 for long
```

so, you have choice:

1. use dec + short jmp, 3 bytes
2. use dec + long jmp, 5 bytes

as soon as most of the loops were (are?) quite short - special short-cut instruction was introduced to reduce size (640kb enough for all):

`loop` which takes only 2 bytes and works as dec + short jmp

so, loop is special "edge" case which I suppose is not used right now (UPDATE: it can be supposed as deprecated ([because it's slow on modern CPUs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35742570/why-is-the-loop-instruction-slow-couldnt-intel-have-implemented-it-efficiently)), and it makes sense as loop forces you to use CX as loop variable, so you cannot create double loop or use another register)

anyway second part of your question - what to do if your loop body is greater:

1. try to optimize it, there are many different techniques, like replace `mov ax,0` (3 bytes) with `xor ax,ax` (2 bytes) and so on
2. re-factor your code into functions (this could actually increase your final size, but reduce body size sometimes)
3. use dec + long jmp

NOTE: these instruction lengths are for 16-bit mode; 32-bit and 64-bit modes use rel32 for long jumps, rather than rel16.

Comment: *instruction lengths are different for 86-286 and 386+*.  No, instruction-lengths are different for 16-bit mode vs. 32 or 64-bit mode.  (jmp rel8 / rel16 vs. jmp rel8/ rel32).  A Skylake or Ryzen in 16-bit mode agrees with a 286 about instruction lengths.