# How to speed up my memory scan program?

Tags: c++, windows, algorithm, memory, assembly

I'm currently writing an Memory Scanner that scans for an AOB in **ANOTHER** process. The aob contains wild card and is represented by a string that looks like`39 35 ?? ?? ?? ?? 75 10 6A 01 E8`

Here's what I have so far:

1. I only have to scan memories regions that matches a specific protection constants. Such as PAGE_READWRITE.
2. However, since I have to scan for large range of memory, it is impossible to read the whole section in to my address space one time. I must do it with a buffer; each time I read in a chunk and process that small chunk. In my program, I held a `currentAddress` variable which stores the address I'm looking at now.
3. Problem with the approach in #2 is that, the aob could lie in between two chunks. My approach to solve this problem is: Whenever the search ended because of end of buffer but the bytes match so far, take N back steps.(Where N is the number of bytes matches.)
4. My algorithm take the naive way; it  brute forces the problem and searches for all possible positions. The code looks like:

   ```
   char *haystack = .....
   short *needle = .... //"39 35 ?? ?? ?? ?? 75 10 6A 01 E8"
   outer:for(int i = 0; i < lengthOfHayStack - lengthOfNeedle; i ++)
   {
       for(int j = 0; j < lengthOfNeedle; j ++)
       {
           if(buffer[i+j] != needle[j] && needle[j] != WILDCARD)
                continue outer;
       }
       //found one?
   }
   ```
5. That was algorithm wise. Implementation wise, I first use `repne scasb` to look for the first byte of needle in the haystack. This process is done by inline assembly. After the index is found, I use c code to compare the rest of it because I need to take care of the wild card.

The performance of my Memory Scanner is okay but I still hope to improve it. What are some ways, both algorithm wise and implementation wise, that I could speed up my memory scanner?

PS: Module of the AOB is unknown. Thus I have to scan the entire memory region.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Other answers here suggest building a DFA, which is linear time.
You can build a [Knuth-Morris-Pratt search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm) instead, and achieve *sublinear* times in many cases.  It skips over chunks of memory that can't contain the pattern, based on bits it has already seen just before the skipped chunk. If you want this to be really fast, I think you'll find that the core algorithm has to be coded in assembler.

2) Rather than read chunks from the target process space (requires copying through the kernel), I'd be tempted to map virtual pages from the target space into the searcher's space.  You can make these pages pretty big (16Mb?) which amortizes the mapping cost; there is zero copying cost.

Comment: Linear with a small, even fractional, constant is still linear.

Comment: @BenVoigt:  True.  OP wanted "faster".  This means if you have a linear algorithm, you want to work on the constant factors.  "Sublinear" means, "smaller constant factor".   In particular, a DFA search will inspect every byte; a KMP search will literally not look at some of the bytes.

Comment: My point is that KMP is not "sublinear", it is still linear but with a smaller scale constant.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Yes, we agree.

Comment: Question, How do I map virtual pages from the target address space?

Comment: Check out *shmget* ("shared memory get"): https://support.sas.com/documentation/onlinedoc/sasc/doc700/html/lr2/z2101586.htm  On consideration, you might have trouble getting the inspected process to co-operate in doing this.  But, that's for you to investigage :-}

Comment: The memory is already allocated and filled with data by the time my program starts searching...So shared memory won't work. @IraBaxter

Comment: I think you should look harder.  I based my suggestion on the fact tha there is no obvious reason that the OS can't map pages from one process into another at the request of the other; that would be especially useful for a debugger.  shmget is a hint that the machinery exists already in the OS.  Maybe it isn't there.  But is surprising what features you find in modern OSes if you look.

Answer (score 2):

## Theoretical answer

Treat your search pattern as a regular expression, and convert it to a [Deterministic Finite Automaton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton), or a `DFA`. Besides this Wikipedia entry, you should find plenty of Google food to investigate.

Basically, the search pattern gets converted into a state machine. The input to the state machine is the byte stream from the memory you're searching, with the final state of the automaton is the state that's reached after encountering the search pattern.

It should be mathematically impossible to come up with a logically faster algorithm, since the input to the state machine is going to be just a linear scan through the memory range, rather than the nested loop approach in your current code. The search complexity should be O(n), linear to the size of memory that's being searched. Don't think it's theoretically possible to achieve better complexity, here.

The regular expression is, basically, a [nondeterministic finite automaton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondeterministic_finite_automaton), or `NFA`, (as indicated in this cited Wikipedia entry) that gets translated into a deterministic finite automaton using the most convenient algorithm available. Then, the memory range to scan becomes the input to the DFA state machine, and as soon as the DFA's final state is reached, the pattern has been found.

## Practical answer

`std::regex_search` takes a pair of bidirectional iterators that define the sequence that's searched for using a regular expression.

Define and implement an iterator class that meets the requirements of a bidirectional iterator, and which iterates over the memory region you wish to search. Convert the search pattern to a `std::regex`, and use `std::regex_search` to search.

A brief scan through the regular expression library's formal definition does not seem to indicate that a `std::regex_search` guarantees maximum complexity of some kind (I might be wrong here, I didn't perform an exhaustive search of the entire library spec); furthermore the fact that it requires bidirectional iterators, as opposed to input or forward iterators, suggests that the implementation might not be as efficient as a bog-standard DFA, but, practically, might require the least amount of work, for reasonably fast results.

Comment: But how do I handle the problem stated in #3 with `std::regex_search` ?

Comment: @Kelvin Zhang You have to implement your custom bidirectional operator so that, when iterating over its sequence, it handles all memory chunks internally, as part of the same sequence. begin() of your custom iterator points the iterator to the first byte of the first chunk. end() points the iterator at the end of the last chunk, and incrementing/decrementing the iterator automatically advances the iterator's internal guts from one chunk to another, when needed, so that the regex engine sees a single sequence comprising all chunks, squished together as a single byte stream.

Answer (score 1):

`repne scasb` [isn't faster than a plain byte-at-a-time loop, unfortunately.](http://agner.org/optimize/)

You'd be much better off scanning for the starting byte with vector instructions:

Use `pcmpeqb` to check a whole vector at a time for a matching start byte.  Use the bit-position of the match as an offset to load the full match candidate.  (An unaligned load is *far* easier than trying to do a data-dependent shift or shuffle, since `palignr` is only available with an immediate count.  Indexing a table of `pshufb` shuffle masks is possible, but doesn't help because you need to load more anyway.

```asm
# load your search pattern into xmm4
#broadcast the first byte to every byte of xmm5
# then
.loop:
    ...
    vpcmpeqb   xmm0, xmm5, [rsi]
    vpmovmskb  ecx, xmm0
    test       ecx,ecx
    jnz    .found_a_0x39_byte
.resume_search:
    add        rsi, 16
    cmp        rsi, rdi  # end pointer
    jb     .loop
...
    .found_a_0x39_byte
    bsf        edx, ecx
    vpcmpeqb   xmm0, xmm4, [rsi+rdx]    ; check against the full pattern (unaligned load, use movdqu if implementing without avx)
    vpmovmskb  eax, xmm0

    ; eax has a one bit for every matching byte
    ; "39 35 ?? ?? ?? ?? 75 10 6A 01 E8"
    ;0b 1  1  0  0  0  0  1  1  1  1  1   reversed because little endian
    not        eax                 ; 0 bits are matching bytes
    test       eax, 0b11111000011  ; check that all bits we care about are zero
    jnz .try_again_with_next_set_bit_in_ecx  ; TODO implement this loop
    # .found_match:
    add        rdx, rsi    ; pointer to the start of the match
```

You need to loop over the set bit positions in ecx, to check all candidate starting points.  Or maybe refine by checking for the 2nd byte of the pattern, left-shift that bitmask by one, and AND it with the first bitmask.  Then you'd have a mask of only the positions where there's a 0x39 followed by a 0x35.

To loop over the set bits:  BMI1's `BLSR` will clear the lowest set bit in the source, and sets `ZF` if the result is zero.  It might be helpful.  (It also sets `CF` if the source was zero to start with, but that's not useful here).  If you can't use BMI1, [there are other ways to clear the lowest bit](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#ConditionalSetOrClearBitsWithoutBranching).

Note that `bsf` sets ZF if its input is zero, even though the output register is undefined in that case.  (Use BMI1's `tzcnt` to get a guaranteed result of `32` or `64` in that case.  Much more useful from C (where a function can't return a value and a boolean), but not always an improvement from asm.)

---

You probably bottleneck on memory bandwidth fairly easily with this, so maybe do something like

```
vpcmpeqw    xmm0, xmm5, [rsi]
vpcmpeqw    xmm1, xmm5, [rsi+1]
```

to only break out of the main search loop when you've found a candidate two byte sequence.  That will cause cache-bank conflicts in Sandybridge's L1, though.  It can only service one load per clock from the same 1/8th of a 128B chunk (2 cache lines).  Intel Haswell and later doesn't have have cache bank conflicts.  In theory, SnB *might* win by using only aligned loads, and using `palignr` to get the unaligned load for the 2nd check.  This would prob. be good on pre-SnB, where there's only a single load port, and you want to use the data for an aligned check as well.

---

To take advantage of a library function for the heavy lifting, GNU libc provides a `memmem`.  It's like `strstr`, but takes explicit sizes instead of operating on null-terminated strings.  You're on Windows, but maybe there's a similar function that has a vector-optimized implementation.  Use it on the `75 10 6A 01 E8` sequence to find potential end candidates.

---

At boundaries between blocks, maybe just do some manual byte-at-a-time checking?  Or use `palignr` to combine the last 16B of one block with the first 16B of the next block in two possible ways?

Maybe only do the `palignr` at all if there's a 0x39 less than 11B from the end of a block?

Comment: But after I replace typical c byte-to-byte code with repne scasb, my program did get faster. (Twice as fast as before)

Comment: @KelvinZhang: Were you compiling with optimization disabled?  `repne scas` isn't terrible, but on Haswell, Agner Fog's table says it does about one byte per 2 clocks.  A well-written loop should easily do one byte per clock, and maybe 2B per clock with some unrolling.

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2013 on Windows 8.1 x64 with optimization `Maximize Speed /O2` @PeterCordes

Comment: A for loop can be faster than `repne scasb` if your for loop compares 4 bytes at the time. Which will still be slower than repne scasd. But comparing 4 bytes at the time isn't practical for me. Because my pattern contains wildcard. Plus you can't assume that pattern will not appear in those address that aren't multiple of 4. @PeterCordes

Comment: @KelvinZhang: A one-byte-at-a-time loop can be at least as fast as `repne scasb`.  Depending on what the compiler did, and what's in your loop, and branch prediction, it might not be.  `repne scasb` does have the advantage of no branch mispredicts when it finds a candidate.  Obviously I wasn't talking about a loop that just did 4B compares.  (Although with bit-hacks [you can check for any byte in a word being a specific value](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#ZeroInWord).  That obviously is nowhere near as fast as an SSE2 loop.)

Comment: In my case, `repne scasb` clearly is faster. How can I optimize the for loop so that it's faster than `repne`?

Comment: @KelvinZhang: There's not a lot of point in spending time optimizing a byte loop, since a vector loop like I posted in my answer will still do better.  But you could try `.loop: cmp [rsi], al / je` / `inc rsi` / `cmp rsi, rdx / jb .loop`.  That should be at least as fast as `repne scasb`, unless branch mispredicts slow it down.  With luck, it will run at one iteration per clock on Intel SnB-family CPUs.  It only has 3 fused-domain uops in the loop, if both compare-and-branches macro-fuse.  If not, it might only run that fast on Haswell, and one iter per 1.333 clocks on SnB/IvB.

Comment: For frequent false-positive candidates, I can imagine that `repne scasb` has an advantage.  Branches in microcode (i.e. the internal implementation of `repne scasb`) can't benefit from branch prediction, so they always have latency, but OTOH they can't mispredict.  This sort of reason is why I suggested doing `pcmpeqw` to break out of the main candidate-search loop 256 times less frequently (assuming a uniform distribution of byte patterns).